# How to change datatype of a table from CHAR to Money

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to change a column datatype from Char to Money through table design. But it's giving error "Cannot Convert a char to money. The Char value has incorrect syntax". Can anyone please suggest how to proceed?

Comment: This is a great place to start: [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/). Please take time out for a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com//tour) and visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com//help). You might also want to read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com//questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for the invalid values like this:

```
select * from TableName 
where colName is not null 
and  try_convert(money, colName) is null
```

These are the values which could not be converted. Change these to valid values then it will succeed.

Comment: Thanks Ben for your quickest reply. I executed the query and got many values that are like "4.54757e-13". What we can convert it to?

Comment: If it contains `e-13` this is a very small number indeed, not a large amount of money. These can be converted to floating-point, but you must understand why they appear in the data before you know what to do with them.

Comment: Make sure you are converting to an appropriate type. `float` only has 14 digits of precision. See also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848794.aspx

Comment: The team who have sent this file is sending another file correcting these values. Though it's a trivial amount they still want them in right figure it seems. But i am marking this answer as helpful in finding the problematic values. Thanks once again Ben.